# ConEmu - How to add per split background logo?

Tags: conemu

How can I add a per split logo to my tabs in conemu? I could do it for all tabs but not per split

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `-new_console:W:"path-to-image"` when defining your splits.

More info: [-new_console syntax](https://conemu.github.io/en/NewConsole.html#syntax)

Comment: Thanks! The transparency of the png appear as black instead of the color of the cmd is this a bug or is this something that is not supported?

Comment: Transparency is not fully supported yet.